# PhP/MySQL - change the URL based on content pulled from MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, url, get

Okay, so I believe my situation is a bit unique (I can be wrong) and I tried to solve this for a few weeks now, but with my very limited PhP/MySQL/Ajax knowledge I can't fix this or find a solution. **Please keep in mind** that my approach may be wrong in total. If you think another approach is more suitable, please suggest what you think.

**What I have**

A database in MySQL with 1000 rows. Every row has these column fields: `ID, UniqueKey, Name, URL`. For example, an item could be like this:

- `ID`: 234
- `UniqueKey`: Rc7AUB
- `Name`: Skeptical Post
- `URL`: http://www.testlink.com/imagedb/image.jpg

I have a script in PHP that **randomly** chooses ONE row from the database, and shows the data on my webpage. So generally speaking, it will show a random image from my database on the page.

**What I want**

I want the URL in the address bar to be updated with the `UniqueKey` (in the example `Rc7AUB`). It is shown like this:

`http://localhost:8888/website/post/#Rc7AUB`

I have achieved it with this:

```
<script>parent.location.hash = "<?php echo $row['UniqueKey']?>";</script>
```

**Why I think this is wrong,** is because this is achieved with javascript.. I don't want the hashtag, I believe this should be achievable with PhP.

**Requirements:** the page cannot reload. On the click of a button, I want the script to choose a new randomly picked row from the database. When this happens, the page will reload the **new** row values into the page, and then I want the URL to update the `UniqueKey` with the **new** UniqueKey that is attached to the newly acquired MySQL row.

I have tried this with `GET` and `POST` but I can't get it to work.. Any ideas?

This is on top of my index.php:

```
<?php
    //session_start();
    //error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include ('pictures_db.php');
    include ('custom_row.php');
?>
```

**pictures_db.php:**

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

**custom_row.php:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM database order by RAND()";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Thank youuuuu!

Comment: PHP is server-side and cannot change the URL dynamically, it can only redirect. Given that, what you're asking is not possible.

Comment: You can't. PHP can't change URL dynamically. You'll have to use Javascript.

Comment: it only possible using javascript